# Server-Sent Event connections are not closed despite calling `close()`

Tags: javascript, client-server, server-sent-events, eventsource

I want to programmatically close the Server-Sent-Events once a user logs out. However when the user logs back in, the browser does not execute any https-requests anymore because it has reached its limit of SSE connections.

I'm using `EventSource` for listening to events.
This is how I close my connections:

```
var eventSource;
function onChange(accountId:string, callback){
    var url = "...";

    eventSource = new EventSource(url);

    if(eventSource){
        eventSource.addEventListener("put", callback);
    }
}

function close(){
    this.eventSource.close()
}
```

When I was observing the network connections on the browser, I realized the connection still exists. The output in `Timing` is: `Caution: request is not finished yet!`, the following event-streams are stalled due to limited number of connections.

I'm not sure if `EventSource` is designed to behave like this, but I could not find anything regarding this issue, since many people don't have the same scenario.
Everytime I reload the page in my browser (chrome) all existing connections are closed, but I don't want to reload the page to workaround this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `this.eventSource` is referring to what you think it is. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this  If called from an event handler it won't be the global scope.

After calling `xxx.close()`, set `xxx` to null. (I doubt that is the problem, but it might help the garbage collection, and also helps find bugs.)

As a 3rd idea of the problem, avoid giving globals the same name as built-in objects. I normally use `es` for my event source objects.

Comment: I made sure that `this` was referring to the correct scope, and set the `eventSource` to `undefined` after closing it, however the connection still persists..
Btw, I'm using typescript (ionic3) and installed `eventSource` using npm, can it have an effect?

Comment: @MerveSahin As you seem to have eliminated the first two (though I would still remove the `this.`, given that it is optional here and can so easily go wrong), have you tried renaming the object to just `es`?  I am not familiar enough with ionic3 to comment; when you say installed with npm, do you mean on the back-end or the front-end? If it is a wrapper around the browser built-in EventSource, then that may well be the problem?

Comment: @MerveSahin Were you able to solve the issue of close ? I have same problem with my ReactJS app.

Comment: @DarrenCook I am curious about what you mentioned about EventSource library from npm being wrapper for browser builtin EventSource. Is there a way to make distinction between the two ? and close both of them ?

Comment: @energycycle It looks like I was asking for more information: EventSource is built-in to the browser, so "installing EventSource using npm" would not be needed, and might be the real problem here.